# adding span tag in jquery not displaying

Tags: jquery, css, html

I'm trying, through an onclick to change the text in an `<asp:linkbutton`.  The code seems to work fine in IE and firefox but is not working in Chrome.

Here is the code i'm using

```
 $('<span></span>', {
    text: icon,
    class: 'WebFonts'
}).appendTo('#' + btn);
```

btn is a parm that is being passed in through the onclientclick function.  Like i said, this is working in IE and firefox.  Here is the webfont css class and chrome will render that when i'm not trying to attach it in javascript.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'WebSymbolsRegular';
    src: url('/font/fonts/websymbols/websymbols-regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('/font/fonts/websymbols/websymbols-regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('/font/fonts/websymbols/websymbols-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('/font/fonts/websymbols/websymbols-regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('/font/fonts/websymbols/websymbols-regular-webfont.svg#WebSymbolsRegular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.WebFonts {font-family:WebSymbolsRegular}
```

greatful for some help
thanks
shannon

~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Here is what your asking for

```
function checkDisableButton(btn, parmText, icon) {
var mbtn=$('#' + btn)
mbtn.attr('disabled', '');
mbtn.addClass("buttonPad buttonProcessing button");
mbtn.text(parmText + "   |   ")
$('<span></span>', {
    text: icon,
    class: 'WebFonts'
}).appendTo('#' + btn);
```

}

and here is what is calling it

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="lbSave" runat="server" CssClass="ButtonPrimary button" Text="Save"
    OnClientClick="checkDisableButton(this.id, 'PROCESSING', 'V');" />
```

and here is what id displayed in Chrome when the asp:linkbutton is clicked

```
<a onclick="checkDisableButton(this.id, 'PROCESSING', 'V');" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbSave" class="ButtonPrimary button buttonPad buttonProcessing" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lbSave','')" disabled="disabled">PROCESSING   |   <span class="WebFonts">V</span></a>
```

You'll notice that the span class="WebFonts" is there in the code

and here is the code before it is clicked

```
<a onclick="checkDisableButton(this.id, 'PROCESSING', 'V');" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lbSave" class="ButtonPrimary button" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lbSave','')">Save</a>
```

So it appears that the span tag is getting put in.. it's just not displaying...
what other info do you need to help troubleshoot?

~~~~~~~~~
Here is some more info.. if i use this instead of jquery... the webfonts shows up

```
  document.getElementById(btn).innerHTML = parmText + '<span class=buttonPad>|</span><span class=WebFonts>' + icon + '</span>';
    document.getElementById(btn).className = 'buttonProcessing button ';
```

just more info.. not sure that i'm getting anywhere

Comment: Can you show us the `onClientClick` as well as the function that runs the jQuery above?

Comment: where is it not working? you forgot the actually include the part that you "like I said".

Comment: Can you add what the html looks like before and what you want after?

Comment: I might be a bit behind with jQuery selector context but shouldn't the second parameter be on object or query string? Also I'd speculate that the "<span></span>" should be "span"

Comment: @MarcB editing mishap ;-) fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key phrase here is:

> Here is the webfont css class and chrome will render that when i'm not
>   trying to attach it in javascript.

Chrome is very picky about when it loads fonts, as it can be a time-consuming task. Try adding a hidden element with that class to your page somewhere:

```
<span style="visibility:hidden" class="WebFonts">V</span>
```

Then Chrome will know to load the font when it renders the page and will be ready when you dynamically add it to the link

Comment: thanks for the this.. i did try it.. i put that code at the top of the content page.  I doubled checked and the line above was in the rendered page.  It did not however solve the issue.

Comment: Hmm... try "visible:hidden" instead of "display:none"?

Comment: that was it.. if you can update your answer.. i'll mark it correct.. Thanks for the answer and the explination

Answer (score 0):

Your code causes a parse error; this should be better:

```
$('<span></span>', {
    text: icon,
    'class': 'WebFonts'
}).appendTo('#' + btn);
```

I've added quotes around the `class`